# How can I hide my table when I click in the sidebar? and Also when I click the button to show another table the current open table will close?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, show-hide

I have different table in every button, and I hide the table by putting the visibility to hide in the css, when I click the button the table will show. The problem is when I click the button again it won't hide the table anymore. And another thing is when I click the other buttons the table which is currently showing will hide then another table will show.

[image: Table picture]

```js
 function toggle() {
          if( document.getElementById("Patient-Table").style.visibility='hidden' )
            {
              document.getElementById("Patient-Table").style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
          
          else{
              document.getElementById("Patient-Table").remove(visibility);
          }
        }
```

```css
#Patient-Table {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="Patient-Table" class="container col-sm-8">
      <div class="table-wrapper">
        <div class="table-title">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <h2>List of <b> Patients</b></h2>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                  <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
             </div>
        <div class="tables border shadow border-3 mt-3 mb-5">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Low</td>
                        <td>Key</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td>27</td>
                        <td>low.key@gmail.com</td>
                        <td>+673668292</td>
                        <td>NewyorkUSA</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='update'>Update</a>
                            <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' href='delete'>Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>2</td>
                      <td>Low</td>
                      <td>Key</td>
                      <td>Male</td>
                      <td>27</td>
                      <td>low.key@gmail.com</td>
                      <td>+673668292</td>
                      <td>NewyorkUSA</td>
                      <td>
                          <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='update'>Update</a>
                          <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' href='delete'>Delete</a>
                      </td>
                  </tr>  
                  <tr>
                    <td>3 </td>
                    <td>Low</td>
                    <td>Key</td>
                    <td>Male</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>low.key@gmail.com</td>
                    <td>+673668292</td>
                    <td>NewyorkUSA</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='update'>Update</a>
                        <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' href='delete'>Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>    
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Don't know if this fixes the problem, but the `=` in your `if` should be `==`.

Comment: Thanks for replying but it doesn't work and if I try to use double equal the table won't show

Comment: Hello Joe, Welcome to SO. Could you please take effort in explaining your doubt clearly. step by step. Like I am unclear about the buttons you are talking about and table associated to them. Thank you.

Comment: Also, one mistake is definitely what  @LinkinTED suggested. You cant assign a value in the expression part of if statement. You are supposed to use "==" or "===". As you said, I dont understand why the table won't show, if you use "=="

Comment: well first I want my table show when I click a menu from the sidebar. Lets say the name of the menu in the sidebar is patient when I click patient the table will pop out and it contains list of patients then, when I clicked again the patients menu the table will hide (vice versa). Thats what I want to happen sir

Comment: by the way I  already solved the problem, well yeah LInkenTED is right I have the problem in = in my if part, then after using == in the if part it is still not shown then I try to rewrite the js code then its worked, maybe I missed something I don'k know. and thank you to your time btw @LinkedTED and DineshPandikona

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function patienttoggle() {
          let patientTable = document.getElementById("Patient-Table");
           if(patientTable.style.display == "none") {
              patientTable.style.display = "block";
           }else{
           patientTable.style.display = "none";
           }
        }
```

Heres my upadted JS CODE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).